# even after null check why I am getting null value in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have tried the following query, wherein I am trying to get the person who has contact and if that contact directed a movie then movie name. in this, I am trying to avoid null for movie names.

but below query is not working, **I have even tried IS NOT NULL.** and m.title <> NULL

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:HAS_CONTACT]->(b)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[:DIRECTED]->(m:Movie)
WHERE m <> NULL
RETURN a.name, b.name,m.title
LIMIT 1
```

RESULT:

```
    a.name  b.name  m.title
"Keanu Reeves"  "Rita Wilson"   null
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably m.title has no value  or does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since an `OPTIONAL MATCH` *does not have to match* (e.g., if a `b` has no `DIRECTED` relationships), your query's `RETURN` clause can legitimately see a NULL `m` (and also a NULL `m.title`).

If you just want to see a (possibly empty) *list* of `m.title` values (any of which could be NULL if that movie has no `title`):

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:HAS_CONTACT]->(b)
RETURN a.name, b.name, [(b)-[:DIRECTED]->(m:Movie) | m.titles] AS titles
LIMIT 1
```